# Is there any Research into using different controls(button,slidebar etc) to perform different actions

Tags: human-computer-interface

Basically I'm trying to find research into the use of different components in a graphical user interface(GUI) to perform different actions. For example: If we're testing Volume, three tests would be A button, a Slidebar and a text box to type in the value. I'm looking for research a long those sorts of lines, but I haven't found any. I know it sounds like common sense, but it's important I back up all my design decisions with evidence based fact. Thanks guy!